# Incrementing number and saving it with put method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a page with two images where you can vote to one of the pictures.
After the voting two new images is loading randomly and so on. The votes should be
incremented and saved to the server, but here comes the problem that I can not put the incremented
number, because I get an array: [{"votes":2},null]
I'd like to increment, save, and load the two new images with one onClick event.

Here it is what I tried to do:

```
handelVote(id) {
this.setState(
  prevState => ({   //I get an array
    voteNr: prevState.castles.map(c =>
      c.id === id ? { votes: c.votes + 1 } : console.log(this.state.voteNr) 
    )
  })

  this.getCastles(),

  axios
    .put("............." + id, {
      vote: this.state.voteNr
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
);


}
```

here I'm getting the data from the server and load only two pictures and the belonging two votes:

```
 componentDidMount() {
if (this.state.castles.length === 0) this.getCastles();
  }


async getCastles() {
    let castles = [];
    let voteNr = [];
    let i = [];

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  const f = z(4); //random nr from Choise.js
  const uniqueSet = new Set(f); //to avoid duplicates
  const b = [...uniqueSet];

  if (b.length < 2) {
    b.shift();
    b.push(1, 2); //in case of duplicates load the first two images
  }

  let res = await axios.get(".....");
  let { data } = res;
  let castle = data;
  this.setState({ castles: castle });

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //load only two
    var t;
    t = b[i];

    let name = castle[t].name;
    let id = castle[t]._id;
    let image = castle[t].image;
    let votes = castle[t].vote;

    castles.push({ image, name, id, votes });
    voteNr.push({votes});
  }


}

this.setState(prevState => ({
  loading: false,
  castles: [...castles]

}));


}
```

and after this comes the already qouted onClick event what makes the problems.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you're expecting to get instead of the data you're getting which is ```[{"votes":2},null]```

Comment: I'm expecting that the number what I get from the server-side should be incremented by one. So the voteNr should be 2 if it was 1 before. /Actually one can vote to a picture and the voted picture's voting number should be incremented by one./